# wpf AutoUpdate dlls?

Tags: wpf, dll, auto-update

I need to update dlls from site in my WPF project. As for .exe or msi file updating is everything clear. But what about dlls? I do not know what to start with or how it should look like... I implemented exe updating through xml file - read xml file from server and if version is higher - load this new version. As for dlls - there are a lot of them, they can be of new versions or new dlls at all... So, I have a question at all - HOW TO IMPLEMENT CHECK? (examples appreciated or just theory answers). And many small questions like If I need to read xml file - how to generate it automatically (to write all dllls not good idea). Waiting for your advice.

Comment: i can't see the difference between updating exe and updating dll. you put the dll version information in the same xml file, and download the dll if new version is found, just like exes.

Comment: @kennyzx ok, and what is the way to form this huge xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33(v=vs.80).aspx).

If `ClickOnce` is not a good choice for you (it has its limitations compared to installers). You can implement you own self-updating mechanism.

Normally this is done by a standalone update util (let's call it `update.exe`), which checks your update website on a scheduled basis.

When you need to deploy a new version of your application (with updated exes, dlls and data files), you can define an XML that list the latest version information of all the files,

```
<files>
    <file name="foo1.exe" version="2.3.0.2" hash="23ac4544490cb3bac23ac4544490cb3bac" downloadurl="youwebsite.com/dl/v23/foo1.exe"/>
    <file name="subdir/foo2.exe" version="5.2.1.1" hash="..." downloadurl="..." />
    <file name="bar.dll" version="1.3.0.2" hash="..." downloadurl="..." />
    <file name="subdir/bar2.dll" version="1.3.0.3" hash="..." downloadurl="..." />
</files>
```

When update.exe is launched, it downloads and parses this xml to determine which files need to be updated, and download these files from the download url, validate the integrity of the files with the hash value, and stop the application to replace the original files, and then restart the application.

**To answer your question as how to generate this huge xml:**

Of course not edited by hand. Write a util that iterates through all the files in the install dir (the latest version), for each file, get the file version (use `System.Version` class), the file size (use `System.IO.FileInfo` class), generates a hash value from the content of the file (use something like `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256`), and form the hugh xml (use `XDocument/XmlDocument` class).

Comment: Ok, thanks.I will try. and write later about results